# If the function preserves angle, then it is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading some problem in Stein Shakarchi's complex analysis.

The question says,

> Conversely, prove the following: suppose $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ is a
> complex-valued function, that is real-differentiable at
> $z_0\in\Omega$, and $J_f (z_0)\neq 0$. If $f$ preserves angles at
> $z_0$, then $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\neq 0$.

I have trouble understanding the question. What is $J_f(z_0)$ and the meaning of real-differentiability? And why do they matter? Can you please explain some context of this question? Also, the question doesn't specify that $\Omega$ is a subset of complex plane, or even metric space. Do I assume that it is a subset of complex plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is $J_f(z_0)$ and the meaning of real-differentiability?

Any complex function $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ can be viewed as a function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$. You can ask whether this function is differentiable, in the conventional multivariable calculus sense. That's "real differentiability".

Being real differentiable at $z_0$ means that there is a linear map $A:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that
$$
f(z_0+z)\approx f(z_0)+Az
$$
for a particular formalized meaning of $\approx$. The matrix representation of this linear map is $J_f(z_0)$. It's called the Jacobian matrix, and it happens to consist of the four partial derivatives of $f$ at $z_0$ (in short, $\operatorname{Re}f$ differentiated with respect to $x$ and $y$, and $\operatorname{Im} f$ differentiated with respect to $x$ and $y$, where $z=x+iy$).

Being real-differentiable is a much less strict requirement than being holomorphic / analytic / complex differentiable. For instance, the complex conjugation map is real differentiable (its Jacobian matrix is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ everywhere). However, it is not holomorphic, as it doesn't preserve angles (it reverses them).

Essentially, a function is complex differentiable iff the linear map $A$ corresponds to multiplication by a complex number (that's what a linear map $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is, so it meshes nicely with the conventional definition of "differentiable"), and this complex number is "the derivative". There are many, many linear maps $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that do not do this. You are asked to show that a non-zero linear map which preserves angles actually does correspond to multiplication by a (non-zero) complex number. That's a different way to view your problem.

And yes, I think it is safe to assume $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb C$. They really should've specified that, but unfortunately they didn't. Maybe they said so a paragraph or two earlier? This excerpt is clearly written as a follow-up to something else (with the "Conversely" at the start).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very little known about differentiability of  the function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and jacobian matrix, but if I understand correctly there is a bijective correspondence between  linear map $A$ and jacobian matrix, and one can see the differentiability of the function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by looking at the jacobian matrix, is that correct way to say it?

Comment: @able20 Yes, that's basically it. There are pathological examples where the Jacobian matrix (i.e. the partial derivatives) exists but the function isn't differentiable. But if each entry in the Jacobian is continuous (as you change which point you differentiate at), then the function is (real) differentiable. And the Jacobian is basically "the derivative" for that function.

Comment: (For a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$, the Jacobian _is_ the derivative as you're used to it, and for $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$, the Jacobian is the gradient.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks so much!